# How to calculate the number of skeletal electrons

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The number of skeletal electrons in CH is 3 and the number of skeletal electrons in BH is 2. How

Comment: Why not? Carbon has one more electron than boron. I assume you're asking about this in the context of Wade's rules?